# About printf (C language)

Tags: c, printf

I want to print a string with multiple lines, I have tried:

```
printf("1. englsih
2. finish
3. japanese);
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have newline characters in string, use `\n`:

```
    printf("1. englsih\n2. finish\n3. japanese\n");
```

If you want to split a string literal to several lines for readability, you can use `\` as the last character on line (not even spaces after it):

```
    printf("1. englsih\n\
2. finish\n\
3. japanese\n");
```

Above has the aesthetic problem, that any indentation at start of line will actually become part of the string. Alternatively, you can just split the string into several `"quoted"` parts, with only whitespace in between, so compiler will combine them into a single string literal:

```
    printf("1. englsih\n"
           "2. finish\n"
           "3. japanese\n");
```

Comment: Thank you very much and I appreciate your modified

Answer (score 0):

Use `\n` to go to the next line, in your text

```
printf("1. english\n2. finish\n3. japanese");
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `\n` or use multiple `printf()`

Option 1 (shorter):

```
printf("1. english\n2. finish\n3. japanese\n");
```

Option 2 (more readable):

```
printf("1. english\n");
printf("2. finish\n");
printf("3. japanese\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

String constants can be multilined, too:

```
printf("1. english\n"
    "2. finnish\n"
    "3. japanese\n");
```

Comment: thank you very much, despite of my english sence is bad, but you comment my question, It help me to active in any forum where use englsih without scruple